# Why stack function works only in selectExpr and not in select

Tags: apache-spark

```
Seq(("Bengaluru",1)).toDF("City","Jan").selectExpr("City","stack(1,'Jan',Jan)").show(false)
+---------+----+----+
|City     |col0|col1|
+---------+----+----+
|Bengaluru|Jan |1   |
+---------+----+----+
```

1> What type of function is stack and why it cannot be used directly in select?
2> How is the stack function able to recognise Jan column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dataset.select](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#select(col:String,cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) takes a single string/column or a list of strings/columns that will be interpreted as *columns of the dataframe*:

> Selects a set of columns. This is a variant of select that can only select existing columns using column names (i.e. cannot construct expressions).

[Dataset.selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#selectExpr(exprs:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) takes a single string or a list of strings that will be interpreted as *SQL expressions*:

> Selects a set of SQL expressions. This is a variant of select that accepts SQL expressions.

`selectExpr` gives you more flexibility as it can process complex SQL expressions. A list of SQL functions that can be used to construct these expressions can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html).

To make things a bit more complicated you can also use `select` with SQL expressions if the expressions are wrapped with [functions.expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#expr(expr:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

From the Scala docs of `selectExpr`:

```scala
// The following are equivalent:
ds.selectExpr("colA", "colB as newName", "abs(colC)")
ds.select(expr("colA"), expr("colB as newName"), expr("abs(colC)"))
```

In your example, the SQL function [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#stack) is used. When parsing the SQL string Spark detects that the first parameter of the `stack` function is a `1` (fixed number), the second parameter is `Jan` (a string literal due to the '  ') and the third parameter is a column name in the underlying dataframe.

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @werner
Is it because stack is not such a  popular method it is not wrapped with functions.expr or is there any other design choice?

Comment: @Vikas I am not really sure how the Spark folks decide which functions to provide via `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` so that they can be used as Scala/Java code and which functions are provided via SQL. I can only guess that there are different ppl/teams working on differents parts of the Spark API.